# Initializing a CodeRef field of a Moose class

Tags: perl, moose

I have a Moose class `Person`

```
 package Person;

  use Moose;

  has 'first_name' => (
      is  => 'rw',
      isa => 'Str',
  );

  has 'last_name' => (
      is  => 'rw', 
      isa => 'Str',
  );

  has 'check' => (
      is => 'rw',
      isa => 'CodeRef',
  );

  no Moose;
  __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
```

I am initializing a new `Person` object in another file like so

```
use Person;

my $user = Person->new(
    first_name => 'Example',
    last_name  => 'User',
    check => sub {
        print "yo yo\n";
    },
  ); 

print "here\n";
$user->check();
print "here\n";
```

The two `here` debug statements are printing but the debug message in the subroutine is not.

I'd like to know the correct way for me to pass a function to the constructor such that I can pass an anonymous sub routine to the object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$user->check()` is equivalent to `$user->check`. It just returns the value of the `check` attribute (i.e, the coderef) without doing anything with it -- just like any other accessor would. The fact that this attribute holds a coderef doesn't change that.

If you want to retrieve the coderef, then call it, you need another arrow:

```
$user->check->()
```

Comment: aha, I see. Thank you! I feel so silly, but your explanation was so clear :)

Answer (score 8):

An alternative is to use the trait `Code` implemented by [Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native::Trait::Code](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native::Trait::Code), and then define a *handle* with a different name.

```
package Person;

use Moose;

has 'check' => (
    is      => 'rw',
    isa     => 'CodeRef',
    traits  => ['Code'],
    handles => {
        run_check => 'execute',
    },
);
```

And then call it like this

```
my $user = Person->new(
    first_name => 'Example',
    last_name  => 'User',
    check      => sub {
        print "yo yo\n";
    },
);

print "here\n";
$user->run_check;
print "here\n";
```

This allows you to separate the accessor for the code-ref from the functionality it fulfills.